# Did Google discover my Tor Route?

Tags: anonymity

I just noticed something weird when using the Tor Browser to access `google.com`.

My entry node was located in France, and the exit node was located in the Netherlands, as can be seen in the image here:

[image]

However Google redirected me to `www.google.fr`, aka the French site, which indicates to me, that it must know what the entry node was.

How can that be? As far as I understood, or is relayed in other questions on this site, e.g. [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/111686/tor-exit-node-can-know-my-ip-address), Google should only know the exit node, right?

Comment: What language settings are you using? Might have picked up on those, if they're not being fully hidden by the browser.

Comment: The browser is set to english, and my operating system is in german.

Comment: what happens if you use a new identity?

Comment: There are other ways to determine location than client IP - edns-client-subnet and geolocation API not to mention LSOs.

Comment: Why using Tor in Chrome? It says on Tor offical website (FAQ): "I want to use Chrome/IE/Opera/etc with Tor.

In short, using any browser besides Tor Browser with Tor is a really bad idea."

Comment: @mirsad I didn't use Chrome. It is the Tor Browser Bundle in the newest version. It just looks a lot like Chrome in the screenshot :)

Comment: @Jay Well it seems to be all over the place actually. Now I just got Google Canada for a France->France->Netherlands route. So it might have been just a freak occurance that it matched with France when I noticed it.

Comment: @Yuriko You are correct. Hard to keep track of all the SE networks.

Comment: Your browser might've had cookies linking you to France from a previous non-torified session.

Comment: Do you use a phone with google services with access to the wifi/gsm/lte/gps? it may be using another device to determine your location.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use Tor, the sites you connect to only sees the IP of the exit node and not your IP or any of the IPs of the previous nodes. This is in fact the very purpose of onion routing. If Google could see that your entry node was in France, Tor would be fundamentally broken.

The happy news is that it isn't. Google does not only rely on IP but uses a variety of [ways to determine your location](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/179386?p=ws_settings_location&hl=en&rd=1):

> ## How location is auto-detected
>
> If you don't set your location, Google shows an approximate location based on the following things to help provide you with the most relevant results:
>
> - Your IP address.
> - Your Location History if you have it turned on.
> - Google Toolbar's My Location feature if it’s turned on.
> - Recent locations you’ve searched for.

That you got redirected to French google when using an entry node in France is just a coincidence. The last bullet point could explain why Tor users gets seemingly random locations. All users using the same exit node (and thus the same IP in Googles eyes) will be asumed to be in the same location by Google.

So probably someone had just googled for a nice bakery in Paris from the exit node you happend to be using.

Comment: Great explanation, I didn't think of all the other users using the node. That makes sense

Comment: This interpretation doesn't hold water. I work with Chrome set to `google.com` and search global `.com` sites almost exclusively, if I only switch to incognito mode I am immediately given Japanese results based on my IP. "Recent locations" here refers to the browser profile, not IP. Just think about it - Google was pioneering move to `https` - why would they reveal now what regions other users use inside their TLS sessions to a random user who happens to use the same gateway?

Answer (score 2):

GeoIP targeting is not 100% accurate, it's *pretty normal* behaviour of any IP-to-geo location service.